# "Imagick::flattenImages method is deprecated and it's use should be avoided"

Tags: php, image, imagick

i cant use flatternImages() function becouse it's deprecated.

I must use

```
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(\Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
$im->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
```

But ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE constant is undefined.

How can i solve this issue?

P.S.
I tried to use 11 instead \Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE and get error:

> "Unable to set image alpha channel"

Comment: Can you say what version of Imagick and ImageMagick you are using....it must be quite old for ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE to not be there.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this answer on php.net](http://php.net/manual/es/imagick.flattenimages.php#116956) you must be using an ImageMagick version prior to [3.2.0b2](http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=imagick&version=3.2.0b2).

At this point, you can either upgrade to the latest version of the library or use the value assigned to the constant `Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE` (which is `11`):

```
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(11); // Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE
$im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
```

Comment: ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE = 12, not 12